# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en la vista en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Realizo una llamada a un WS y recibo unos datos, el problema es que no se cómo mostrar los datos que recibo

Mi controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Consulta(Models.SolicitudesViewModels.Consulta consultar)
    {
        var token = Session["token"] as string;

        SRSolicitudes.SolicitudesSoapClient wsSolicitudes = new SRSolicitudes.SolicitudesSoapClient();
        SRSolicitudes.ConsultaSolicitudes outConsultaSolicitudes = new SRSolicitudes.ConsultaSolicitudes();
        outConsultaSolicitudes = wsSolicitudes.ConsultarSolicitud(token, consultar.Estado, consultar.Cedula, consultar.Nombres, consultar.Apellidos, consultar.Computacion, 1, 50);

        ViewBag.resultado = outConsultaSolicitudes.Cantidad;
        ViewBag.Ocultar = false;
        ViewBag.Mostrar = false;

        return View();
    }
```

Mi vista:

```
    @model Demo.SolicitudesViewModels.Consulta
    <section>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <h2>Consultar Solicitudes</h2>
    @if (ViewBag.Ocultar == false)
    {
        <h3>Se encontraron @ViewBag.resultado resultados.</h3>
    }
    <form name="buscando" action="@Url.Action("Consulta", "Solicitudes")" method="POST">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="text-right">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buscar" />
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("Inicio","Home")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Salir</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>
                    Cédula<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cedula, null, new { @class = " form-control" })
                </th>
                <th>
                    Apellidos <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Apellidos, null, new { @class = " mayusculas form-control" })
                </th>
                <th>
                    Nombres  <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nombres, null, new { @class = " mayusculas form-control" })
                </th>
                <th>
                    Nro. de Computación <br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Computacion, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </th>
                <th>
                    Estado <br />
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Estado, new SelectList(new[] { null, "Aprobado", "Rechazado" }), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </th>
                @if (ViewBag.Mostrar == false)
                {
                    <th>
                        Categoria
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Acciones
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
            @if (ViewBag.Mostrar == false)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedula</td>
                    <td>Apellido</td>
                    <td>Nombres</td>
                    <td>NroComputacion</td>
                    <td>Estado</td>
                    <td>Categoria</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> <span>Ver</span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

aqui es donde quiero mostrar mis datos como una tabla

```
            <tr>
                    <td>Cedula</td>
                    <td>Apellido</td>
                    <td>Nombres</td>
                    <td>NroComputacion</td>
                    <td>Estado</td>
                    <td>Categoria</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> <span>Ver</span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

la llamada se devuelve cantidad y solicitudes que es una array y contiene lo siguiente

```
    <ConsultaSolicitud>
        <IdSolicitud>int</IdSolicitud>
        <Estado>string</Estado>
        <NroComputacion>int</NroComputacion>
        <Cedula>string</Cedula>
        <Apellidos>string</Apellidos>
        <Nombres>string</Nombres>
        <Fecha>dateTime</Fecha>
        <Categoria>string</Categoria>
      </ConsultaSolicitud>
```

Comment: buen día hermano, ya que andas aprendiendo sobre ASP.net MVC, te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el workshop que hice hace un tiempo sobre dicho tema, el link del código fuente está en la descripción del video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo pienso que debes cambiar la calse model view Consulta y agregar un listado de Consultas Solicitud

```
public class Consulta
    {
        public string  Estado { get; set; }
        public string Cedula { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Computacion { get; set; }
        public List<ConsultaSolicitud> ConsultaSolicitud { get; set; }
    }
```

entonces en el controlador asignas el resultado del WS a la lista de  ConsultaSolicitud

```
consultar.ConsultaSolicitud = new List<ConsultaSolicitud>();
consultar.ConsultaSolicitud = outConsultaSolicitudes;
```

y retornar la vista con el objeto consultar.

```
return View(consultar)
```

en la vista puedes iterar sobre los elementos de la lista ConsultaSolicitud y llenar la tabla

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ConsultaSolicitud ){
<tr>
    <td>@item.Cedula</td>
    <td>@item.Apellido</td>
    //las otras columnas
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> <span>Ver</span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: resolvi asi como dijiste solo que le hice un pequeño cambio en el controller en la asigancion del ws a la lista

Answer (score 0):

No veo que estes enviando un modelo a la view, en el action `Consulta` deberias enviar los datos

```
return View(outConsultaSolicitudes);
```

de esta forma en la view defines

```
@model List<SRSolicitudes.ConsultaSolicitudes>
```

con esto tendrias lista para iterar y crear la tabla

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Cedula</td>
        <td>@item.Apellido</td>
        //las otras columnas
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> <span>Ver</span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: ya utilizo un @model en mi vista, y entonces lo que hice fue crear un modelo que a la vez contenga los dos modelos que estaria usando, pero me da un error

Comment: entonces el modelo imagino lo creas en el action y lo envias a la view mediante return View(). pero cual es el mensaje de error que recibes? podrias actualizar la pregunta incluyendo esto que has realizado